# How is closure implemented with nameless lexical addressing

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

In [EOPL](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/eopl/), chapter 3, exercise 3.28. It ask me to construct closure with bindings of ONLY those free variables, instead of the entire environment. But after parsing, all variables have been replaced with their lexical address, for example:

```
(lambda (x)
   (lambda (y)
     (+ x y)))
```

will become:

```
(lambda (x)
  (lambda (y)
    (+ (var 1 0) (var 0 0))))
```

Where the first number is the depth, and the second number is the position.

My question is:

**How can I tell if a variable is a free variable in a expression where all variable are nameless?**

Answer (score 2):

They have a rib number greater than their depth of occurrence in the expression consider that in:

```
(lambda (x)
  (lambda (y)
    (+ (var 1 0) (var 0 0))))
```

Once the outer is removed `(var 1 0)` has a rib of `1` where as the depth of occurrence of the reference is `0` so `(var 1 0)` is free in:

```
(lambda (y)
    (+ (var 1 0) (var 0 0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if I get it. Are we always comparing the rib number against 0? What if I have program with multiple nested lambda?

Answer (score 2):

Keep a single counter of how many times you see a new closure and have a environment where you bind the variables to the index and depth. Evaluate the body so that symbols can be resolved and you do `(list 'var (- framcount var-frame) var-index)` Example:

```
(lambda (x)
  ;; evironment count=0, x=(0,0)
  (lambda (y)
     ;; environment count=1, x=(0,0), y=(1,0)
     (+    ; + is a global (no match),      (glob '+)
      x    ; x is frame (- 1 0) and index 0 (var 1 0)
      y))) ; y is frame (- 1 1) and index 0 (var 0 0)
```

You could also just keep frames so that the resolver counts the number of frames it hasn't found the variable as well as the index it finds it. That way there is no need for a count variable. It's probably many more ways to do this.

- As you can see you spot the globals by you not finding it's position.
- You know the variable is bound by it having frame 0. `(= count row)`
- You know it's a free variable by it having greater than 0 frame.

Comment: Awesome, this is really helpful. But then what format should i use for the closure environment? When i find those binding and add to an environment, I need to sort them in the same order as they are in the old environment, so i can find those bindings when i look up. I've been thinking but seems like i cannot lookup by using lexical address cause the closure env only contains certain bindings of free var

Comment: @Jackddddd If you've made some Scheme interpreters you have probably either used an assoc list where you add your bindings to front, eg full relative address to the root could be `((y . (1 . 0)) (x . (0 . 0)))` and when the farme gooes out of scope you have `(x . (0 . 0))` and count=0, but you could do it even simpler by just adding the prototype list in front so you have `((y)(x)` and you just search each sublist n a way where you cound ho many elements. For a stack the leftmost variable should be top of stack (0) to support `apply` curry, but for a free variable structure it doesn't matter.

Comment: My current env implementation is list of vectors, it is nameless and contains only value and can be looked up by depth and position.

Comment: @Jackddddd That sounds more like what the runtime should be using rather than the parser??

Comment: @Jackddddd Yes, but it's a two step process. The whole point in doing the frame+index thing is to run the program as a stack machine thus when running there are no`x`, `y` or `+` but the symbols have become primitive operations instead. The parser makes the transition and it works as an interpreter only the result is a different version of the program that can be run by the runtime more efficiently . An even better approach would be to only do closure conventions on the variables that are sure to be used when the variable is no longer on the stack.